# django |safe template not working properly

Tags: html, django

Django |safe template not working properly

I tried to use a textarea as rich text in Django admin, all good, but when I try to show in front with {{ date|safe }} it only shows a maximum height of proximate 200 cm which doesn't allow to show all the text

I already read the Django docs article. I do not know what to do.

display in front
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzjF5.png

code HTML

```
  {% block content %}
  <div     
  style="height: 1000vh; "
  >
    {{ personaje.bio|safe }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

use summer notes for this rich text box
https://i.stack.imgur.com/stHIT.png

I had used it before but I don't know what the problem is

Comment: You've set height to **100vh** which is height of your viewport either remove height or set ``overflow-y: scroll;``

Comment: At what point did I define it at 100vh?, already set how to  overflow-y: scroll; but no work

Answer (score 0):

Write this

For example, p comes from loop and content is your content or paragraph.
write => truncatechars_html

```
{{p.content|truncatechars_html:150|safe}}
```